# Fail to initialize dependencies. Singleton class using Dependency Injection (Ninject)

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

I want a singleton class that uses dependency injection (ninject) start as soon as the application starts. The singleton class resides in Domain layer(Class Library) -
 Domain.Concrete.Operations. And I'm using this class in WebUI layer(MVC).
I'm stuck at initializing dependencies in static constructor of the service that I plan to start in Application_Start method. What is the right way to do it?

**Singleton class:**

```
    namespace Domain.Concrete.Operations
{
    public sealed class SingletonClass
    {
        private IInterface1 _iInterface1;
        private IInterface2 _iInterface2;

        public SingletonClass(IInterface1 iInterface1, IInterface2 iInterface2)
        {
            this._iInterface1 = iInterface1;
            this._iInterface2 = iInterface2;

            StartAllOperations();
        }

        public void StartAllOperations()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

**NinjectDependencyResolver:**

```
    namespace WebUI.Infrastructure
{
    public class NinjectDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
    {
        IKernel kernel;

        public NinjectDependencyResolver(IKernel kernelParam)
        {
            kernel = kernelParam;
            AddBindings();

        }

        public object GetService(Type serviceType)
        {
            return kernel.TryGet(serviceType);
        }

        public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
        {
            return kernel.GetAll(serviceType);
        }

        private void AddBindings()
        {
            kernel.Bind<IInterface1>().To<Class1>();
            kernel.Bind<IInterface2>().To<Class2>();

            kernel.Bind<SingletonClass>().To<SingletonClass>().InSingletonScope();
        }
    }
}
```

As far as I understand this code will help to return the same instance of SigletonClass:

```
kernel.Bind<SingletonClass>().To<SingletonClass>().InSingletonScope();
```

**Service in App_Start:**

```
    namespace WebUI.App_Start
{
    public class OperationManagerService
    {

        private IInterface1 _iInterface1;
        private IInterface2 _iInterface2;

        static OperationManagerService() //static constructor cannot have parameters 
         {
            _iInterface1 = //how to initialize 
            _iInterface2 = //interfaces here?
        }

        public static void RegisterService()
        {
            new SingletonClass(_iInterface1, _iInterface2);
        }
    }
}
```

**Register service in Application_Start (Global.asax.cs):**

```
    namespace WebUI
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {


        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            OperationManagerService.RegisterService();
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I must admit that I'm able to initialize dependencies like this, but then I can only use the OperationManagerService class in controller. **Not in Application_Start!**

```
            static OperationManagerService(IInterface1 iInterface1, IInterface2 iInterface2)  
         {
            _iInterface1 = iInterface1;
            _iInterface2 = iInterface2;
        }
```

This leads me to thought that I can't use injection with Ninject in Application_Start. If it's true, then where is the right place to create a class that should load at startup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to intermix the [Singleton pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx) with [Ninject's Singleton Scope](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes), which confuses who is trying to construct what when. Don't use the old the Singleton pattern when trying to use DI. Half of the point of DI is to manage the lifetime (scope) of the objects it contains. You do this by specifying `.InSingletonScope()` as you have done.

Now, onto your question of injecting dependencies into a startup feature: you will need to allow Ninject to construct the `OperationManagerService` in order to have the dependencies provided by Ninject. To do this, register it in Singleton scope, as you did with `SingletonClass`. The **first time** it is requested from the Ninject container, it will be constructed and injected with the necessary parameters. Singleton scope only tells Ninject to only ever construct one instance.

However, it seems that you would like it to be constructed during startup? If this is a requirement, something will need to ask for it. The simplest solution would be to get it after binding it:

```
private void AddBindings()
{
    kernel.Bind<IInterface1>().To<Class1>();
    kernel.Bind<IInterface2>().To<Class2>();

    kernel.Bind<SingletonClass>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
    kernel.Bind<OperationManagerService>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();

    kernel.Get<OperationManagerService>(); // activate

}
```

If you find yourself doing this alot, I have used a simple "auto-start" pattern:

```
public interface IAutoStart()
{
    void Start();
}

public class SomeClassThatStarts : IAutoStart
{
    public void Start()
    {
        Console.Log("Starting!");
    }
}

public class AutoStartModule : Ninject.Modules.NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        foreach(var starter in Kernel.GetAll<IAutoStart>())
        {
            starter.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Register the `AutoStartModule` last in your Kernel, and any `IAutoStart` will be loaded with any dependencies and started.

Comment: Thank you very much Dave!  Yes indeed, I've added kernel.Get<OperationManagerService>();  to my AddBinding method and it created needed instances at startup. I'll also read the links you've attached to your post! Thanks once again! Have a nice day!!!